# Display an item from a object that has been put in a self variable

Tags: python

Basically I have a process class that takes in 3 variables. `process` as in the name, time and io.

I put that `process` into a ready `queue` then in another class I have put the first object from `readyqueue` into `self.__ current`. Usually when I put the object into a variable eg. `current = process('hi', 6, False)`. I can say `current._process.__time` and it returns >>> 6.

Can anyone explain how i can do this with `self.__current`.

```
class Process:
    def __init__(self,process,time,io = False):
        self.__process = process
        self.__time = time
        self.__io = io

class cpu(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        self.timequantum = 1
        self.__current = []
```

Comment: It's always nice to have explanation what you want to do and what you get or don't get. But it's always important to have it also as code that can be verified.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is because you're using attribute names that start (and don't end) with two underscores. When you do that in a method, it invokes Python's "name mangling" feature, which transforms a name like `__process` into `_Process__process`. That makes it awkward to access from other code.

The purpose of the name mangling system is to allow mixin classes to assign attributes on objects that may have any number of other attributes. Since the mangling adds the name of the class where the attribute is being used (not the name of class of the object), the mixin-author can be fairly confident that no other class will accidentally use the same attribute name.

You probably don't want name mangling, so you should not use `__` at the start of your attribute names. If you want the attributes to be "private", use a single underscore, which indicates that the attribute is not part of the public API of the class. This is a convention, so for debugging or testing you can still access the `_` prefixed attributes if you need to.

Or if you want other code to use the attributes, just use bare names. In Python, it's perfectly acceptable to have public attributes as part of an object's API. (Other programming languages discourage that, but in Python you can reimplement an attribute-API with getter and setter functions using a `property` later if you need to.)